# Delete multiple lines from file when text is found

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed

I've seen multiple answers to delete a single line with `sed` or `grep`, but I'm in need to search for a line, delete that one, and the 2 proceeding lines. For example, in the file `~/.profile` I have lines like:

```
#Set environment variable
export NAME=value
# (blank line here)
```

So I'd like to search for `#Set environment variable`, and delete it, then delete the next line `export NAME=variable` (content shouldn't matter), and the following blank line. The `export` variable names are dynamic, but the comment will always be the same. There could be other `export` variables without the above comment which I do not want to delete.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the newer version of GNU `sed` (comes with Ubuntu), you can match the newlines literally:

```
sed -z 's/#Set environment variable\nexport [^\n]\+\n\n//g' file.txt
```

- `-z` option will treat the lines of input files as terminated by ASCII NUL rather than newline, thus we can use `\n` to match the new lines
- `#Set environment variable\n` will match the first line (with new line)
- `export [^\n]\+\n` will match the second line starting with `export`
- As the third line is blank simply `\n` will do
- Then we replace the whole pattern matched with blank to keep the desired portion

In you want to overwrite the file with the modified content:

```
sed -zi.bak 's/#Set environment variable\nexport [^\n]\+\n\n//g' file.txt
```

The original file will be retained as `file.txt.bak`, if you don't want that just use `sed -zi`.

Here is a test:

```
$ cat file.txt 
#Set environment variable
export NAME=value
#some text

#Set environment variable
export NAME=value

check
value

export some=value

#Set environment variable
export NAME=value

foo bar



$ sed -z 's/#Set environment variable\nexport [^\n]\+\n\n//g' file.txt 
#Set environment variable
export NAME=value
#some text

check
value

export some=value

foo bar
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do this with standard sed's delete command:

```
cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.bak
sed '/#Set environment variable/,+2 d' <~/.profile.bak >~/.profile
```

Be careful with your ~/.profile

Comment: this is not right....it will blindly remove the next two lines after match regardless of the contents....also you can just use `sed -i` instead of taking a backup beforehand..

Comment: @heemayl : but original post said "(content shouldn't matter)", at least for the "export" line. You might be right with the blank line, though.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question makes it look like you're looking for a command-line way to do this, if I were in your situation and only wanted to do this for one or two files, I would use `emacs`.

`emacs` has the capability of learning a sequence of keystrokes and then repeating them as many times as you want. So in your case I would open `~/.profile` in `emacs` and then type

`C-x ( C-s #Set environment variable C-a C-k C-k C-k C-x )`

[which, in words, does this: C-x ( means "start learning this"; C-s means "search for", so then we search for #Set environment variable, and then C-a means "back to the beginning of the line, and the three C-k's mean "delete this line", and finally C-x ) means "stop learning this".]

After those commands have been typed once, emacs has deleted three lines, but it has also learnt how to do it by heart, so you can now type

`C-x e`

and it will do it again, or

`C-u 100 C-x e`

and it will do it 100 times (or stop when it can't find any more lines with "#Set environment variable" in).

The advantage of using emacs is that you can see your edits happening "live", and for a paranoid person like me who is scared that one sed typo can delete lots of stuff that I didn't want deleted, this makes me much happier [the moment things go wrong in emacs you can just go backwards and fix them with `C-_`].